# expo run:android - AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/show_buffering' with config ''

Tags: android, react-native, expo

When I run `expo run:android` my app crashed with the error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource compilation failed
     /Users/joel/Developer/dnp/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:7014: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/show_buffering' with config ''.

     /Users/joel/Developer/dnp/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:7014: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

     /Users/joel/Developer/dnp/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
```

The iOS build works (`expo run:ios`).

I have tried to change `minSdkVersion` in my `build.gradle` and i've changed similar values in that file to try and fix it, with no success.

I am running:

- react-native@0.64.3
- expo@44.0.6